# Converting all vars to global scope

Tags: php

I know I can use $GLOBALS['var'] inside a function to refer to variables in the global scope.
Is there anyway I can use some kind of a declaration inside the function so I will be able to use $var without having to use $GLOBAL['var'] every time?

Joel

Comment: The variable scope has a purpose. Why do you want to revert that?

Comment: This is doable, but most likely a very bad idea. See @Gumbo's question

Comment: I totally agree that this is a bad idea. But this is solely for practicing, to better understand how to create such a thing when in need (even though, again, it is a bad idea)

Comment: polluting the global namespace with variables that other functions/classes don't need will most likely bite back at you. so be warned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not recommended, but if you do want to, here's what you can do:

If you **only want to GET the values from the vars** (and not SET the values), just use [`extract`](http://php.net/extract):

```
extract($GLOBALS);
```

This will extract and create all the variables in the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

How about using static class?
such as

```
class example
{
  public static $global;
  public static function set($arr)
  {
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
      self::$global[$key] = $val;
    }
  }
}

function example_function()
{
   var_dump( example::$global );
}

example::set( array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2) );
example_function();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `global` keyword, So you can use type `$var` instead of `$GLOBALS['var']` inside a function.

```
function myFunc() {
  global $var;
  $var = 3;
}
$var = 1;
myFunc();
echo $var;
```

Output: 3